# Background styles

Tags: html, css

I've to achieve what the image attached is displaying

[image]

The image with the blue filter is part of a scrolling banner (using bxslider). The arrow has to show the image that is underneath it, as the attached image shows

So far I've managed to add the arrow as a pseudo element with a white background, but I can't see how to add that transparent background right behind the arrow...

```
.bx-wrapper:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: block;
    content: "" ;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: white url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-ui-outlined-thick/24/chevron-down-512.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 10px 20px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Have a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe4sp87m/)

Comment: You can create an white image having a transparent half circle and cover your slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to resolve it with [radial-gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_radial-gradient.asp).
I post you a solution using 2 pseudo-element: one for manage transparent background and one for manage your arrow.

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  controls : false, 
  auto : true, 
  pause : 10000
});
```

```css
.my-slider {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}


li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(1, 176, 169, 0.75);
}
    
.bx-wrapper::after,
.bx-wrapper::before{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

.bx-wrapper::after {
    bottom: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0, transparent 10%, white 10.1%);
}

.bx-wrapper::before{
    bottom: 8%;
    background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-ui-outlined-thick/24/chevron-down-512.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 6%;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="my-slider bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=Slide 1" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=Slide 2" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=Slide 3" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=Slide 4" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150&text=Slide 5" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```